# Tomcat7.0.100 can't provide java backend api services

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7

To resolve the AJP problem, we updated tomcat to v7.0.100 and config the conf/server.xml file in Host item as below :

```
<Context docBase="D:\app" path="/" reloadable="true" />
```

The front resources such as js, html

[image: are ok]

But the API backend service does not start and any requests return 404 error.
Catalina.out shows below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 创建类型为 [xxx.manager.inter.websocket.service.WebSocketDemo] 的 POJO 实例失败
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointServer.onOpen(PojoEndpointServer.java:60)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.init(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:135)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:680)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.DefaultServerEndpointConfigurator.getEndpointInstance(DefaultServerEndpointConfigurator.java:40)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointServer.onOpen(PojoEndpointServer.java:57)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.DefaultServerEndpointConfigurator.getEndpointInstance(DefaultServerEndpointConfigurator.java:36)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at xxx.common.context.ApplicationContextManagement.getBean(ApplicationContextManagement.java:26)
        at xxx.manager.inter.websocket.service.WebSocketDemo.<init>(WebSocketDemo.java:36)
        ... 13 more
```

Code line 36 in WebSocketDemo.java:

```
 private SpeedService speedService =  (SpeedService)ApplicationContextManagement.getBean("speedService");
```

We debugged the Tomcat source code and found a bug at line 111 in /org/apache/catalina/startup/WebappServiceLoader.java:

```
Enumeration<URL> resources = ((URLClassLoader) loader).findResources("/" + configFile);
```

Comment: It looks like a bug in your `ApplicationContextManagement` class.  We can't tell you much more without seeing the code.

Comment: i don't think so.   because when the same app is deployed in tomcat-7.0.61,  all are ok.  And we don't change any code.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

did you add secretRequired="false" to connector in server.xml ?, this something new to tomcat

or you can make it true also but need to provide secret phase.

Comment: we've cancled the ajp。